# Access SQLite database using content provider from PHP page on the same Android device?

Tags: php, android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have php page running on the Android device and have Android app installed on the same device. Is it possible to access SQLite database using content provider(content://com.example/table_name insert query) from PHP page on the same Android device?

Thanks,
Gaurav Kapoor

Comment: What does that mean: 'a php page running on a device'?

Comment: Where is that sql database resided? Which app does it maintain?

Comment: Which app would have that content provider?

Comment: Your setup is pretty unclear to me indeed.

Comment: We are running web page on dedicated Android device like a tiny server and now we want to enter data into the mobile application SQLite database using that web page. Means wants to share database with web page.

Comment: In which browser is this php page displayed?

Comment: Should php query for that content provider? And you did not tell to which app belongs the provider. You also did not tell why you think it would be possible or even not possible to access a provider. Please explain what you have in mind.

Comment: Web API in php to query content provider of android app.